# Add Blank Cell to each Group in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a tableview that has groups. I would like to add a dummy cell at the top of each group, but not add it to the data. I dont want it saved. So if the top cell is clicked, its data passed will be blank and I can handle  the passed view differently. I currently am configuring the cells manually.

So if group one had two entries, the display of those two entries would be prepended with a fake entry at what would be index 0

Below is a preview of what I am trying to do.

[image]

PS: Can one cell have a different disclosure icon? Does that break  Interface Guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this, you are not really adding anything to your model, you are just modifying your view:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if ([indexPath row] == 0) {
        //And any other default behavior
        [[cell textLabel] setText:@""];
    }
    else{
        //Your code for each cell


    }
    return cell;
}
```

The [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW42) doesn't mention anything about having different disclosure icons:

```
iOS includes some table-view elements that can extend the functionality of table views. Unless noted otherwise, these elements are suitable for use with table views only.
```

Comment: this code would null out the first entry and not prepend a dummy cell though? Am I reading that right?

Comment: What would happen is that when the `UITableViewController` call this method, only the first cell (at the row 0) would contain nothing and any other cells would contain whatever is in your datasource. If you were not looking for this, then I misunderstood your question. Would you mind explaining it more? :S

Comment: oh. when I click on a cell it shows me a view of a semi random result, and when I return the blank cells are gone? what would cause them to not be 'sticky'?

Comment: Oh, this is because you also have to add that if statement or a similar one in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and respond by not pushing another view :D